How to protect API routes in next js with next auth
I want to secure my API routes in next js I tried the getServerSession method it works but only on client side I want to use both side please I need solution. I have a admin API and I want to make only for admin and for both side for client and server. Also on next-auth I tried the credentials provider but it's not providing the access token.
Secure API routes in next js
this is i am using now in middleware - ` const AdminAccessAPI = req.nextauth.token?.role !== "ADMIN" && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/admin") && req.nextauth.token?.isVerified !== true
if(AdminAccessAPI){
    return NextResponse.json("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
}

`  but this is not working on server side and server components

You can protect routes in next.js by adding middleware.ts (or .js based on the language you choose to code) and add the following code.
middleware.ts
    export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

    export const config = {
        // specify the route you want to protect
        matcher: ["/dashboard"],
    };


i want to protect next js api routes not pages

apologies. If you want to protect api routes. you can check  auth token on headers like in middlware in express.js like this:
req.headers.token

but next-auth not provide token for credientials providers because of some security reason i don't know without access token is any way to secure routes?
